# init / inittab respawn (count number of times it occurs)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, process, init, inittab

I added the following line in my /etc/inittab to respawn a program if it crashes.

```
#test must always run.
aa:2345:respawn:/home/pi/test/test
```

Is there a way to know how many times the init/respawn event occurs ?
Is there a log file for inittab ?

I'm using Raspbian Wheezy and Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this directly solves your problem, but you could use something like supervisord activity logging for desired outcome. http://supervisord.org/logging.html#activity-log

Other process supervisors like [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) and [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) might also have this functionality.